# Geometry Nodes instancing faces (Update Blender 3.0)

Tags: faces, instances, geometry-nodes

How to make Instancing Faces and aligned to face normal in Geometry Nodes?
[image]

I tried blender 3.0. Mesh to Points node solved instancing in the middle of a triangle. But aligned to face normal weird. Here image:
[image]

Comment: You are asking how to align point instance position to center of face and align rotation to face normal, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Align Rotation to Vector, Vector should be "`normal`" and axis Z (for default cone):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And how make one Point Distribute in one tris?

Comment: I do not found the answer yet. I guess, it is not developed yet. Note, that it is the first scope of geometry nodes, hope it will be in future releases.

Comment: This answer aligns point instances to mesh vertices normals, which are different than the OP's request for two things: align point instance position to center of face and align rotation to face normal. Is this even possible? I'm searching for the answer myself.